# Negative long is returned?

Tags: iteration, long-integer, factorial

In this iterative factorial equation any number that I pass through greater than 39 appears negative. Why is this

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long var = formula(40);
        if(var != 0){
        System.out.print(var);
        }
        else{return;}
    }
    public static long formula(final int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            System.err.println("No negative numbers");
            return 0;
        }
        long ans = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            ans *= i;
        }


        return ans;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of something called overflow.  There are limits to the values that certain types can hold.  If you go past the limit on an integer type's value, you encounter integer overflow.  Here's a link about [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) with some more specifics.

The gist is that a factorial is an exponential function that grows rapidly, so it doesn't take long to wind up with a value that will not fit into a long integer.  When you see negative numbers it's because you have exceeded this limit.  The limit is platform dependent, but is often around 4,294,967,295 for an unsigned long int.

Using the limit above, you would only be able to calculate factorials up to 12!, 13 and above would overflow.

Comment: I was in the process of doing so when you commented.  You are correct though, and my answer is now updated along with a link to bountiful information on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, I was just confused as to why it turned negative, it seems that it should print out infinity or 0 but I guess not

Comment: You could increase your maximum value by using an unsigned long int instead of a long int.  It effectively doubles the limit.  This won't help you much from a point of view of computing factorials though.